# Запятая нужна в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

> Космонавт номер три, дважды Герой Советского Союза...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На снимке  ... **космонавт номер три, дважды Герой Советского Союза, генерал-майор авиации** Андриян Григорьевич Николаев. http://znamya-truda.ru/index.php/raznoe/5158-kosmonavt-nomer-tri

Запятые поставлены, так как в данном случае эти приложения считаются однородными, вероятно, **из-за нестандартного оформления званий**.

**Пример оформления неоднородных приложений**: командир космического корабля «Союз-40» Герой Советского Союза лётчик-космонавт СССР Л. И. Попов.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=99#pp99

Вообще говоря, **однородность и неоднородность приложений  в достаточной мере условна.** Достаточно сказать, что при расположении неоднородного ряда после определяемого слова он становится однородным. Поэтому постановка запятых в приведенном примере **представляется вполне оправданной.**